# When user slides to view a notification and app is in foreground.Can we make it go to a spcific controller in app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have an app in which i have push notifications working properly but when a user slides can i make it go to a specific controller.

If anyone could direct me in the right way.
That would be a great help.

Thnx

UPDATED

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {


BeepsDetail *objCont = [[BeepsDetail alloc] initWithNibName:@"BeepsDetail" bundle:nil];
objCont.mId =@"1600";
objCont.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[[self navigationController ] pushViewController:objCont animated:YES];

[window addSubview:navigationController.view];  
[objCont release];}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your app delegate should implement this method;

```
 - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application 
              didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

Inside this method, you can do whatever you want to, such as instantiate a view controller and add it's view as a subview to the main window, or put up a modal view, etc.

Comment: Hi i was doing some what you said only but if u look at my updated code i want to do it as to presentModalView controller coz this code is showing a blue color navigation bar dat i dnt want

Comment: Then replace `pushViewController:objCont` with `presentModalViewController:objCont`

Comment: Did app crashes and also gives me a warning while doing this

Comment: Then go back to using the `pushViewController` but also add this line:  `[self navigationController].navigationBarHidden = YES;`

Comment: Also i have a back button bt since its a modalview controller self dismissmodalviewcoller doesnt work...

Comment: my app is based on presentModalViewController and wen i do pushViewController and controller comes rest of d presentModalViewController get disabled and i am not able to go to...

Comment: `    [[self parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
`